# PHP Installation on RHEL

Tags: php, linux, installation

Am trying to install and configure PHP 5.2.17 - 32 bit on RHEL6.2 but am getting error while configuring as below :

`checking libxml2 install dir... no checking for xml2-config path... /usr/bin/xml2-config checking whether libxml build works... no configure: error: build test failed.`

Please, let me know how to install 32 bit PHP on RHEL 6 Thanks, viswa

Comment: Why do you specifically need the 32-bit version?

Comment: Try with rpm package.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would simply use `yum` its such an awesome tool. `RHEL 6` supports that easily, you don't need to then build an install yourself. (Only unless you want to customize things)

```
yum install php
```

and it will take care of dependencies too

Comment: Hi Hanky, Thanks for your reply,.. I have install 32bit version of php and i want to configure specific folder option also.. It seems that "yum install" will install 64bit version as my OS is 64bit....

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install php.i386
```

might work.

Comment: hi yum install php.i386 not working, Shows the below error:[root@sehan9419as001 php_5.3_32Bit]#  yum install php.i386
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package php.i386 available.
Error: Nothing to do